# Calculate Lightsail Monthly Cost based on Specific Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

I have many Lightsail Instances of my different clients. I have to create different cost calcuation for my different clients.

How can I create a monthly cost calculation by filtering specific instances. Is there any mechanism to create filter the monthly cost of lightsail instances with thier tags?

Answer (score 0):

Better later than never. You could attach a tag called "Client" to each instance and populate it. The billing dashboard can then be used with the standard per-tag filtering to get a cost per client.